# how to rebuild a tuple with some modification?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, I got a tuple

```
a = ('chicken', 1, 'lemon', 'watermelon', 'camel')
```

I want to build a new tuple `b` from `a` but change a little bit

```
d = {0: 'apple', 1: 'banana', 2: 'lemon', 3: 'watermelon'}

b = (a[0], d[a[1]], a[2], a[3], a[4])
```

another way to do it

```
b = list(a)
b[1] = d[b[1]]
b = tuple(b)
```

All of them work, but look silly.

Is there another elegant way to do this job? or are there some skills to modify the original tuple?

Comment: If you intend to change the value often, try to use a list/dict, as tuples are immutable objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit inefficient in comparison to yours because it does a check on every item, but the general idea is that it looks at each item in your `a`, checks for a matching key in `d` and if it finds one, returns the value at that key. If no key is found, the original item is returned:

```
In [1]: a = ('chicken',1,'lemon','watermelon','camel')

In [2]: d = {0:'apple',1:'banana',2:'lemon',3:'watermelon'}

In [3]: b = tuple(d.get(x, x) for x in a)

In [4]: b
Out[4]: ('chicken', 'banana', 'lemon', 'watermelon', 'camel')

In [5]: type(b)
Out[5]: <type 'tuple'>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "elegant", but if you want something more generic that just replaces elements in the 'a' tuple that have a key in 'd', you can use a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) and do something like:

```
>>> a
('chicken', 1, 'lemon', 'watermelon', 'camel')
>>> d
{0: 'apple', 1: 'banana', 2: 'lemon', 3: 'watermelon'}
>>> tuple(d[x] if x in d else x for x in a)
('chicken', 'banana', 'lemon', 'watermelon', 'camel')
```

It constructs a new tuple, since tuples are immutable.